# how to unlock phone which gs no internate connection

Tags: locked-out

How can I unlock my phone since it needs Google account sign in , while my phone has no internet connection neither wifi connection.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether its your phone or not. but try this:

Download Android ADB files over the internet. Look for your phones models, Fastboot mode. enter into fastboot mode.

1. Connect you (turned on) Phone to the Computer via USB.
2. Open a command prompt terminal window, move to the location where you have your adb files.
3. Enter below commands in console:

adb devices

adb shell

cd data/system

rm *.key

Done...Now You Just Have To Reboot.